# '@mui/system' should be listed in the project's dependencies

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, eslint

I have just installed MUI v5.4 in my create react app typescript project and I wanted to import

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/system';
```

but eslint keeps showing this error

```
'@mui/system' should be listed in the project's dependencies.
```

and @mui/system is in my dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.16.7",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.3",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.4.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
    "@types/redux-saga": "^0.10.5",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
},
```

I've tried this solution below in .eslintrc but it didn't work

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": true}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and @mui/system is in my dependencies in package.json

I don't see it there. You have `@mui/material` and `@mui/styled-engine-sc`, but not `@mui/system`.

Do `npm install @mui/system` to fix this.

Comment: so embarrassing I was seeing "@mui/material" as "@mui/system" for about an hour now thank you I've installed it and it works